# Select elements in a list when the firsts two items are the same (no matter order) and its third element is lower

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I'm trying to solve a heuristic search in Mathematica 9. I get a list of succesor nodes called open with two nodes and a heuristic value, e.g.,

```
open={{node1,node2,H1},...,{node2,node1,Hi},...,{noden,noden,Hn}}
```

I need to select only when the two first elements are the same (no matter order) but where the heuristic is lower. Following the code that I used for sort the elements by the first item

```
Sort[open, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]
```

I try to select cases when the same first and second numbers and the heuristic value where lower:

```
Select[open, #1[[1]]==#2[[1]] &&  #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] && #1[[3]]< #2[[3]] &]
```

But, returns `{}`...

My list

```
open = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}};
```

Between `{1, 2, 3}`, `{1, 2, 2}`, and `{2, 1, 5}` then choose `{1, 2, 2}` that has the lower heuristic. And, between `{3, 4, 5}` and `{4, 3, 2}` then `{4, 3, 2}`...

```
{{1, 2, 2},{4, 3, 2}}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Just as a remark: in your `Select` statement, you're using `#2`, but this won't do anything. The function in `Select` is a function of 1 argument only and the `#2` slot will never be filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
First[Sort[#, #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &]]&/@Gather[open, Complement[Most[#1], Most[#2]] === {}&]
```

> {{1, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}

this is a combination of two functions: First you gather the same edges and then you sort them according to their weight and take the first element (which has the lowest value.)

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain me a little deeper what did you do? especially, the last part...

Comment: @user7892  If you mean the `Complement[Most[#1], Most[#2]] === {}` part, it's just a way using basic principles from set theory for gathering the same edges.

Comment: I did an effort to get it...yeah, in that part, you drop out the ones with same two firsts member. Thanks again,

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `GatherBy[]` and `SortBy[]` does the trick:

```
First[SortBy[#, Last]] & /@
GatherBy[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}}, Sort[Take[#, 2]] &]
   {{1, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In versions 10+, you can use `MinimalBy` combined with  `GroupBy`:

```
open = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 3, 2}};

Values @ GroupBy[open, Sort[#[[;; 2]]] &, First @ MinimalBy @ Last]
```

> {{1, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}

Or, `MinimalBy` combined with `Merge`

```
Values @ Merge[First @ MinimalBy @ Last][Sort[#[[;;2]]] -> # &/@ open]
```

> {{1, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}

Or, combined with `GatherBy`:

```
First @ MinimalBy[Last] /@ GatherBy[open, Sort[#[[;; 2]]] &]
```

> {{1, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}

For older versions, a combination of `SplitBy` and `SortBy` also works

```
First /@ SplitBy[SortBy[open, {Sort[#[[;;2]]]&, Last[#]&}], Sort[#[[;;2]]]&]
```

> {{1, 2, 2}, {4, 3, 2}}

Comment: Pardon me, but none of these seem better than J.M.'s `GatherBy` method.  Would choose any of these in practice over it, and why?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, no claim is made about better:)